# Убрать заголовок приложения

Tags: actionbar, android

Добрый день, есть необходимость в приложении убирать на некоторых формах ActionBar, как это сделать програмно?
хотел ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); - приложение вылетает с ошибкой, (Android 2.3.4) 
находил другой вариант
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  - не убирает заголовок приложения
Каким способом мне можно убрать название экшена на форме?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка возникает потому что `getActionBar()` доступен с API 11. Лучше использовать  SupportLibrary и убирать следующим образом:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Супер! Все нормально работает, СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: Остается чуть заметный след от ActionBar.. как же все-таки правильно убрать его?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужна поддержка 2.3, то юзайте SupportLibrary, а лучше [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).